# How do I pull by tag from multiple git repos in Azure Pipelines YAML?

Tags: git, azure-yaml-pipelines

I have a YAML pipeline that does a nightly build pulling from multiple Azure Git repos with the YAML `checkout` task.  Now we are ready to release a version of the product built by this pipeline.  The version will be "2.1".  My idea was to create tags ("2.1.204") and specific "Release 2.1" branches for each repo and move the mainline on to version 2.2.

So now I must create a "Release 2.1" pipeline that will pull the code from these repos ***with a specific tag*** that I've applied to each of them.

How do I do this with the `checkout` task?  Must I do it some other way?  I'm not very good with Git or YAML pipelines for that matter but this task fell on me so I have to learn.

Here's how I checkout currently:

```
   - checkout: git://Software/Sdk
     displayName: 'Get SDK Source code'
     persistCredentials: true
   - checkout: git://Software/ThirdParty
     displayName: 'Get SdkThirdParty'
     persistCredentials: true
```

When I'm editing the YAML and I type in the `-checkout` YAML task, I get the following options, none of which looks like I want

```
 - clean
 - condition
 - continueOnError
 - enabled
 - env
 - fetchDepth
 - lfs
 - name
 - path
 - submodules
 - target
 - timeoutInMinutes
```